# Can you use create advantage to get a free invocation more than one time on the same aspect?

Tags: fate-core, aspects, create-advantage, free-invocations

Let's imagine a scenario were the player doesn't want to spend fate points on a combat, so he want to stack several free invocations to go for a big hit in a conflict.

This conflict happens on a old house and has the situation aspect "Dust everywhere" the PC is fighting against a NPC.

The player wants to create a few freebies on that aspect. So the first turn he declares that he wants to jump and circle around the NPC to raise dust and obscure his vision. The next turn he wants to create and advantage again throwing a handful of dust to the NPC's face. And so on...

This is just an example, but the question remains.

**Can you use create advantage on an existing aspect more than one time?**

**Can you stack free invocations?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, to both

When [creating an advantage](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/four-actions#create-an-advantage), you have the option to create an advantage on an existing aspect. Success give you 1 free invoke, and success with style gives you two. There is nothing in the text that says you can only do this once.

As for [free invocations](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/invoking-compelling-aspects#free-invocations), keep in mind that "*[y]ou can…stack multiple free invocations together.*"

Doing what you're talking about is Fate working as intended. Doing a bunch of set-ups for the final, knock-out blow is very much what CaA is *supposed* to do.

Comment: I would consider adding that denying large numbers of repeated Create Advantage actions on the same aspect, due to it not making narrative sense, is *also* Fate working as intended (see the Silver Rule). If I throw sand in someone's eyes and blind them, then throwing more sand isn't going to make them any blinder.